# Are the instance created using ninject are automatically disposed at the end?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ninject

Are the instance created using ninject are automatically disposed at the end?

Cause I am using Entity Framework and I bind `IContext` to an instance of a new context. Will this context be Disposed at the end?

If not how can I Dispose it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The end

of what?

The standard mechanism in Ninject is the [Cache and Collect](http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20) mechanism, which non-deterministically `Dispose`s when garbage collection opts to release weakly-referenced [parent scope objects](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes).

If you're in an ASP.NET app (or WCF pipeline with `HttpContext` wired up), `.InRequestScope` will deterministically `Dispose` at the end of a request.

The real answer to your question is that this is a duplicate of 50 other EF/DI Container Dispose questions around here - I suggest you put a little more effort into finding those and maybe next time give more context.

Be careful of putting too much into one Unit Of Work and letting the system take care of it - most of the time you want to know what your Transaction unit is and not consider things such as committing and error management around that to be a triviality.

Comment: .InRequestScope seem to be what i was looking for. I was talking about the end of the application.

Comment: @Rushino: OK, just for avoidance of doubt then, typically `IDisposable `wont get triggered at app end - in theory `InSingletonScope()` could be but aren't, and Transients never do (other containers do require a Release for transients - Ninject effectively says that's  a waste of time and doesnt track Transient-scoped objects)

Comment: Are you saying .InRequestScope doesn't ?

Comment: No, not saying that - InRequestScope gets disposed at end of an individual HttpRequest context - not App, Session end or any other end

Comment: @downvoter Please explain your frustration - perhaps I can improve my answer or someone else can write one that can answer your question

Comment: They should force writting a comment in such case... i think your explanation was useful i dont see anything wrong here.